# Select all except some rows

Tags: sql

let's say i have table with this structure:

```
  id      model       color
------  --------    ----------
   1      Ford           yellow
   2      Ford           green
   3      Ford           red
   4      Ford           yellow
   5      Subaru         yellow
   6      Subaru         red
```

I need to make a query, which returns me every car in list, except for yellow ford's. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
... WHERE NOT (model = 'Ford' AND color = 'yellow')
```

Comment: You're right Foo Bah, my query didn't work (sorry nukl, I should think twice before posting)

Comment: @Vincent Savard we all make these kinds of mistakes

Answer (score 5):

If you want to deselect some rows dynamically, you may use it:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_1` WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM `table_2` WHERE column_name='value')
```

NOTE: Here, **id** is a column_name, which both tables have in common.

Good luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Foo Bah's answer,

if you have null column values like that;

```
NAME      COLOR

Ford      green               
Ford      red                 
Subaru    yellow              
Subaru    red                 
Subaru    NULL
Ford      NULL
```

you need to use ISNULL() function to bring null column values

```
... WHERE  NOT (ISNULL(NAME,'') = 'Ford' AND ISNULL(COLOR,'') = 'yellow')
```

Comment: Only if he wants to exclude nulls

Answer (score 0):

Use Color<> "yellow" and model <> "Ford" as your where clause

Comment: You are filtering out the green and red Ford and the yellow Subaru

Comment: you're right... I was thinking about it backwards.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
    $this->db->where('model !=','FORD' AND 'color!=','yellow');
    $query= $this->db->get('table_name');
    $res = $query->result_array();
    return $res;
```