# how to get all rows except with specific values

Tags: php, mysql

Hello is there a way to only get the `survey_name` that the organisation has not used yet?

```
`survey table`
+-----------+-------------+
| survey_id | survey_name |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 | name1       |
|         2 | name2       |
|         3 | name3       |
|         4 | name4       |
|         5 | name5       |
+-----------+-------------+

`link table`
+---------+-------------+-----------------+
| link_id | survey_link | organisation_id |
+---------+-------------+-----------------+
|       1 | 1(survey_id)|        1        |
|       2 | 2           |        1        |
|       3 | 2           |        2        |
|       3 | 3           |        2        |
|       3 | 6           |        2        |
+---------+-------------+-----------------+
```

In this database structure you would see this for each organisation:

available surveys organisation1:

- name3
- name4
- name5

available surveys organisation1:

- name1
- name4
- name5

I have tried using 
`WHERE NOT (survey_id= $row['survey_id'])`

```php
//get all survey's that are in use
$sqlCheckLink = "SELECT `survey_id` FROM `link_info` WHERE `organisation_id`=".$_SESSION['organisation_id']."";
    $resultCheck = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCheckLink);
    if ($resultCheck ->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($id = $resultCheck -> fetch_assoc()) {
            //show all surveys that are available
            $sqlGetSurveys = "SELECT * FROM `survey_info` WHERE NOT (survey_id = ".$id['survey_id'].")";
            $resultAllSurveys = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlGetSurveys);

            if ($resultAllSurveys ->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $resultAllSurveys-> fetch_assoc()) {
                   //echo content
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198748/select-all-except-some-rows)
But it does not seem to work...
With this method I get also the surveys that are in use.

If someone could help it would be really appreciated!

Comment: `SELECT survey_name FROM survey_table WHERE survey_id NOT IN (SELECT survey_link FROM link_table)` will give you what you need. You may add `organisation_id` in inner SELECT if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much this solved my question!

Comment: mitkosoft answer is correct but on big queries, "NOT IN" are so slow. Once I read anywhere "NOT IN always can do it with a JOIN", in this case is possible too.

Comment: @juanram0n is there an alternative?

Comment: I post an answer, hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just using LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT t.survey_name
FROM survey_table as t
LEFT JOIN link_table AS l ON l.survey_link = t.survey_id
WHERE l.link_id IS NULL
```

Not tested, but you can get the idea.
I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately I did not get this to work. But I am using tables with pagination so it will probally not become so slow. Thanks for your time